# How to enter punctuation symbols using Chewing (zhuyin) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, input-language, input-method, chinese

I'm currently using Chewing (Zhuyin) IME on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm a bit confused as to how to enter punctuation symbols as I type.

For example, punctuation symbols I'm referring to are simple, common symbols, like `。` or `，`. Or other symbols that are a bit less common.

Those symbols were copied from online webpages which uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift` +  `<` = `，`

`Shift` +  `>` = `。`

`Shift` +  `!` = `！`

`Shift` +  `?` = `？`

`Shift` +  `:` = `：`

`Shift` +  `(` = `（`

`Shift` +  `)` = `）`

`[`  = `「`

`]` = `」`

..... etc.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/ChewingUserGuide

I'm going to copy the relevant info from the page:

> Talking about inputing Chinese symbols, other then enable "Easy symbol
>   input" mode, you can also press {Ctrl-1} to open up a symbol selection
>   dialog, select the category, then use {Down} key to choose the symbols
>   as you would do for characters.

[image]

Thus far, I haven't yet found a better way to quickly access the punctuation symbols by using 1 shortcut key press, and have to resort to using 3 shortcut key presses to initiate my selection. Like, if I were to select a period symbol, I have to do:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to bring up the menu dialog.
2. <kbd>3</kbd> to choose the common symbols.
3. <kbd>3</kbd> for the period.

If anyone knows of a better method, please share below. Thanks.